# WordPress Permalink structure to find products with tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks, wpml

I'm using Wordpress with WooCommerce and WPML. For Permalink structure I'm using Permalink Manager. Everything works fine until I want to search with Make or Make and Model tags.

```
http://shop.localhost:7773/category1/ - found, showing
http://shop.localhost:7773/category2/ - found - showing

http://shop.localhost:7773/category1/?make=bmw - found, showing bmw
http://shop.localhost:7773/category2/?make=bmw&model=335 - found - showing bmw 335


http://shop.localhost:7773/category1/bmw/ - 404 not found
http://shop.localhost:7773/category2/bmw/ - 404 not found

http://shop.localhost:7773/category1/bmw/335/ - 404 not found
http://shop.localhost:7773/category2/bmw/335/ - 404 not found
```

Maybe someone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Due to the missing trailing slash perhaps?

Comment: @04FS No. I tried both ways.